# Model Checking a Linked List

Tags: model, spin

I looked in SPIN model checker. However, it does not have features for dynamic allocation.
Is there any other model checker that i can use for dynamic allocation?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve dynamic allocation in a number of ways.  In all of them you need to have an upper limit on the number of allocations (that is usually not a limiting factor).

You will define a structure type for the stuff that you want to allocate and you will put a number of these into an array.  You will use an index into that array to reference the structure.  So, a bit like this:

```
#define data_t byte

typedef data_record {
  data_t me;
  bool allocated;
  // .... your data fields here ....
}

#define NUMBER_OF_DATA_RECORDS 10

data_record data_record_array[NUMBER_OF_DATA_RECORDS];

#define DATA_RECORD_ALLOCATED(dt)    data_record_array[(dt)].allocated
#define DATA_RECORD_ME(dt)           data_record_array[(dt)].me
```

Now you can define some `inlines` to allocate and free these.  There are a number of options.  For example, to allocate, just iterate through `data_record_array` to find a `data_record` that is not `allocated`.  A bit like this:

```
// Assigns data_ptr with a free data_record index
inline data_record_allocate (data_t data_ptr)
{
   data_ptr = 0; 
   do
   :: data_itr >= NUMBER_OF_DATA_RECORDS -> break
   :: else ->
        if
        :: ! DATA_RECORD_ALLOCATED (data_itr) -> 
           DATA_RECORD_ALLOCATED (data_itr) = true
           DATA_RECORD_ME (data_itr) = data_it
           break
        :: else -> data_itr++
        fi
   od
 }
```

and then free is like:

```
inline data_record_free (data_t data_ptr)
{
  DATA_RECORD_ALLOCATED (data_itr) = false
  data_itr = NUMBER_OF_DATA_RECORDS
}
```

A little more sophisticated would be to put all the free indices, which at the beginning is all indices, into a channel of 'free indices`.  When you allocate just read from the channel; when you free just push back onto the channel.